# Get list item "Likes" using JSOM or REST API's?

Tags: 2013, rest, client-object-model

How can you retrieve a list items "Likes" using the JSOM or REST API's? I know there is the following method: SP.Social.SocialFeedManager.getAllLikers(postId), but in testing I was not successful using the "posts" item id as the methods postId.

Any help or direction as to how this is done would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where you using the posts ID (around two or three digits long) or its GUID?

Comment: Hi Robert, I did try both methods, passing in the int ID as well as the item GUID. Maybe I am not loading my client context correctly? If you could provide an example, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Better you copy paste in your code here so everyone can see it, and maybee spot some errors :)

Answer (score 3):

I found an article (link below) that had a code snippet to get all likers (Graphic).  Sounded like it might be useful for your problem.

http://www.techbubbles.com/sharepoint/social-features-in-sharepoint-2013-part2/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a CSOM example [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2013/07/08/how-to-use-csom-with-ratings-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) that's simply pinging a list item's "AverageRating", "RatingCount", and "Ratings" props to give you the item's rating info. The challenge though is in converting this to JSOM...

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://yourSiteUrl")){
    Web w = ctx.Web;
    List l = w.Lists.GetByTitle("yourListName");

    CamlQuery cq = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
    ListItemCollection lic = l.GetItems(cq);

    ctx.Load(lic, items => 
        items.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
        item => item.Id,
        item => item["AverageRating"],
        item => item["RatingCount"],
        item => item["Ratings"]));

     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     foreach (ListItem li in lic){
          Debug.WriteLine(li["AverageRating"]);
          Debug.WriteLine(li["RatingCount"]);
          Debug.WriteLine(li["Ratings"]);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the following JSON code in [this posting](http://wp.sjkp.dk/sharepoint-2013-add-like-functionality-to-publishing-page-with-javascript/) demonstrating how to add 'Like' functionality to a publishing page with Javascript.  Presumably, the 'LikedBy' property would also be exposed for any list/library with [ratings setting enabled](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Enable-users-to-rate-content-fe6302dc-d521-4a56-99a6-133b63ee7afc).

```
    var likepage = {
    //Likes the current page. 
    LikePage: function () {
        likepage.getUserLikedPage(function(likedPage, likeCount) {

            var aContextObject = new SP.ClientContext();
            EnsureScriptFunc('reputation.js', 'Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation', function() {
                Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.
                    Reputation.setLike(aContextObject,
                        _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.substring(1, 37),
                        _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId, !likedPage);

                aContextObject.executeQueryAsync(
                    function() {
                        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('likecount');
                        if (likedPage) {
                            likeCount--;
                        } else {
                            likeCount++;
                        }
                        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length;i++) {
                            elements[i].innerHTML = likeCount;
                        }
                    }, function(sender, args) {
                        // Custom error handling if needed

                    });
            });
        });

    },
    // Checks if the user already liked the page, and returns the number of likes. 
    getUserLikedPage: function (cb) {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
        var item = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId);

        context.load(item, "LikedBy", "ID", "LikesCount");
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (success) {
            // Check if the user id of the current users is in the collection LikedBy. 
            var $v_0 = item.get_item('LikedBy');
            if (!SP.ScriptHelpers.isNullOrUndefined($v_0)) {
                for (var $v_1 = 0, $v_2 = $v_0.length; $v_1 < $v_2; $v_1++) {
                    var $v_3 = $v_0[$v_1];
                    if ($v_3.$1E_1 === _spPageContextInfo.userId) {
                        cb(true, item.get_item('LikesCount'));
                    }
                }
            }
            cb(false, item.get_item('LikesCount'));
        }),
            Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) { 
            //Custom error handling if needed 
            }));
    },
    initialize: function () {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('likecount');
        likepage.getUserLikedPage(function(likedPage, likesCount) {
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].innerHTML = likesCount;
            }
        });
    }
};
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("likepage.initialize");
```