# How to get comments counts using SocialDataService

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, comments, social-comment

I'm at my wits end with this problem.
basically, what I'm trying to do is activate comments and ratings on my pages (the pages have managed navigation.

I've added comments using the SocialCommentControl control on my page and it's working fine, except i cant get the right comment count for that page.

I later found out that on the social db, the url that gets associated with the comment is not the friendly one but a rather long one having termId, termstoreId and termSetId

So, to count the comments I am doing

```
function commentCount(managedContextInfo, urlContextInfo, itemId){
        var articleUrl=urlContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl.replace(urlContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl,'')+urlContextInfo.serverRequestPath;
        articleUrl+="?TermStoreId="+managedContextInfo.termStoreId;
        articleUrl+="&TermSetId="+managedContextInfo.termSetId;
        articleUrl+="&TermId="+managedContextInfo.termId;
        articleUrl+="&UrlSuffix="+itemId;

        var soapEnv =
            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \n" +
            "<soap:Body>\n"+
                    "<CountCommentsOnUrl xmlns='http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/SocialDataService'> \n"+
                        "<url>" + articleUrl + "</url>\n"+
                    "</CountCommentsOnUrl>\n"+
                "</soap:Body>\n"+
            "</soap:Envelope>";

        jQuery.ajax({
            headers: {
                "Accept": "text/xml",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            processData: false,
            url: "/_vti_bin/SocialDataService.asmx?op=CountCommentsOnUrl",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError + "\nResponseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log(data);               
            }
        });
}
```

I am calling this function with 
`_spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo`, `_spPageContextInfo` and `ctx["CurrentItem"]["ListItemID"]`.

As is, this code returns a `Error: 400 Bad Request`

By trial and error i found out that (don't know if its the sole reason) the character "&" present in the variable `articleUrl` is causing some form of xml formatting error.
If I replace it with "%26", use encodeURI(articleUrl) or encodeURIComponent(articleUrl) at best I get a valid response but the count is always zero.

Now, I am constructing the url this way because I know its the way its stored on the database `SharePoint_UserProfileSocialDB`. The way I see it, the problem is that I'm encoding it one way and the webservice SocialDataService is decoding it in some other way.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Consider replacing `?` with `%3F`.

Comment: You can look at this thread as well:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67633/get-list-item-likes-using-jsom-or-rest-apis/73677#73677

Answer (score 1):

as it turned out, i had to encode the ampersand character as & amp ;.

Comment: So did you get it figured out?

Comment: better use encodeURIComponent()